# tcl regexp match a string of digits based on index of the string

Tags: regex, tcl

I am in need of a little help. I am trying to come up with a regexp to match a string of digits. I want the string to match starting at a position value of the string I have.

here is the string I have

```
01102000000000001A40000000200000000000100012064000100000000000000
```

I want the regexp to match starting from the 20th value of the string or directly after the A4. Also I want to match the first say 10 digits after the 20th value of the string. I have tried a few things they are not really working. Wanted to see if I could get some idea's here.

Comment: Why are you using regex if you just want 10 characters from position 20? TCL appears to support string.range to do just that...

Comment: Actually I tried the string range already. apparently this is all one giant character                                                           lindex match 0
01102000000000001A40000000200000000000100012064000100000000000000       if you see lindex value 0 is this whole string. I would need to find a way to break the break the string. That is why I figured might be easier to use regexp here.

Comment: @Matt: The `lindex` command is for getting elements from lists. Look up the `string` command, specifically `string range` which does what you want done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case the link in TessellatingHeckler's answer goes stale, I'll add another answer with the actual code. There are at least three solutions to this problem (assume the string to search in is in the variable `s`):

TessellatingHeckler's solution:

```
lindex [regexp -inline {.{19}(\d{10})} $s] 1
```

Another `regexp` solution:

```
regexp -inline -start 19 {\d{10}} $s
```

A `string range` solution:

```
string range $s 19 19+9
```

Documentation: [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)

Answer (score 2):

A regex to match the first 19 characters up to A4 and throw them away, then capture 10 digits after that into a group:

```
.{19}(\d{10})
```

http://regex101.com/r/cO9bE7/1

(I don't know if it's TCL compatible, though).

Comment: That is a possibility that is what I was going to try if I could't do it the other way. I am not sure if TCL regexp has support for matching on a position value and then a range after that. But your suggestion is something I have thought about also. Thanks for the suggestion as well.

Comment: Hi Just tried this, it is TCL compatible so thanks for the help. I really appreciate this.

Comment: This is a link only answer and as such should be posted as a comment instead of an actual answer. Please make sure that people can use our answer alone without any links for the solution and use the link only for extra information.